# Possible to write a shebang that tests if a shell/execution environment exists at specified path?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

In shell scripting, is there any way to construct the shebang so that it tests for existence of the specified shell or execution environment, and if it's not there, tests for another, and finally chooses one that exists?

Or alternatively, can you list multiple shebangs at the top of the script, and if the first one fails, it tries the next, and so on until it find ones that exists?  Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash --
#!/usr/local/bin/bash --
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#!/bin/sh --
```

Comment: The standard solution is `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to find it on your PATH - is that not sufficient?

Comment: You only get one shebang line so if searching PATH doesn't work for some reason then the caller has to specify their interpreter explicitly when calling the script if they want something other than what the shebang provides.

Comment: You basically never want to fall back between `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/bin/sh`. You should use bash if your code is written to run in a shell with bash extensions. You should use sh if your code is written to run on a strictly POSIX-compliant interpreter. It's either/or: if your code is written to be sh-compliant, you should always be using sh: either it'll be faster to start up if your distro ships a smaller shell like ash or dash, or it'll be bash-in-compatibility-mode and behaving in a more POSIX-y way than full extended bash.

Comment: @tjm3772 That relies on the assumption that `env` resides in `/usr/bin` and `bash` is installed. Nothing standard about it.

Comment: @oguzismail shebangs in general rely on the declared program being installed and existing at the specified location, so to the extent that you have to assume those things to make shebangs work anyways I would consider it perfectly standard to solve the problem of "I know I want this to run bash but I don't know exactly where bash will exist."

Comment: @oguzismail, ...you're right that POSIX doesn't require that specific location and so it's not standard-enforced, but `/usr/bin/env` is generally a pretty safe assumption -- even the most oddball Linux distro I know (NixOS) has it as one of exactly two executables with well-known, non-hash-addressed names (the other one is `/bin/sh`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy but it does require that an executable file that is not recognized as a process image be executed as a shell script. You can check in your script if it is being executed by bash, and if not, call `exec bash $0`.

Comment: The purpose of the shebang is to specify a *known* interpreter on a specific machine so that you can execute something that is not otherwise a native binary. It's not meant to make your script "portable" across multiple machines.

Comment: You could use `/bin/sh`, and use code to check for a preferred interpreter, then `exec` to restart the script using that interpreter if one is found.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `/bin/sh`, and use code to check for a preferred interpreter, then `exec` to restart the script using that interpreter if one is found.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = -skip-check ]; then
   shift;
else
   if ...; then
      interpreter=...
      exec "$interpreter" "$0" -skip-check "$@"
      exit 1
   else
      echo "Couldn't find a suitable interpreter." >&2
      exit 1
   end
fi

...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Possible to write a shebang that tests if a shell/execution environment exists at specified path?

Sure. The following shebang tests is bash exists, if so, runs it, else runs sh.

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S sh -c 'if hash bash 2>/dev/null; then bash "$@"; else sh "$@"; fi' sh
```

I would not do that. I see no value in "listing multiple shells", either I write a POSIX compatible shell script or I write a bash script, I do not see a value in mixing them. Prefer just `#!/usr/bin/env sh`. The user environment should be configured so that `sh` is in `PATH` and is able to run POSIX compatible shell scripts.

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to work: shebang parsing isn't required to handle this many arguments.

Comment: See https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve -- there's _exactly one_ optional argument that the execve call agrees to handle; even if there are spaces, an exec implementation is allowed to concatenate them together into a single argument. Quoting that doc: *For portable use, optional-arg should either be absent, or be specified as a single word (i.e., it should not contain white space); see NOTES below.*

Comment: ...quoting from that NOTES section, bolding added: *The semantics of the optional-arg argument of an interpreter script vary across implementations. On Linux, **the entire string following the interpreter name is passed as a single argument to the interpreter**, and this string can include white space. However, behavior differs on some other systems. Some systems use the first white space to terminate optional-arg. On some systems, an interpreter script can have multiple arguments, and white spaces in optional-arg are used to delimit the arguments.*

Comment: Yes, in this example you have `env -S` doing the split, but it's a GNUism ([POSIX `env`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html) only specifies one argument, `-i`) and so considerably more nonportable than, say, an assumption that `/bin/sh` will exist would be.